Angular 17 Reactive Form: Radio Buttons Always Checked on Load Despite Boolean Values
I'm working on an Angular component that uses reactive forms with radio buttons. I want to create three radio buttons representing a boolean choice (true or false). The radio buttons are initialized with values from a reactive form control. However, when the component loads, all radio buttons appear as checked, regardless of the actual boolean values in the form control. The values for each radio button are correctly taken from each formControl value.
<div>   
<input type="radio" [id]="radioItemId" [name]="name" [formControl]="_control" [value]="value" (change)="emitItem()">   
</div> 

export class ReactiveRadioSelectComponent {
  _control!: FormControl;
  @Input() set control(control: AbstractControl) { this._control = control as FormControl; }
  @Input() radioItemId = '';
  @Input() name = '';
  @Input() value = false;

  @Output() itemChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
}

<div>
  <app-reactive-radio-select [name]="'group' + index" 
                             [radioItemId]="'hasSensor' + index"
                             [control]="_slotsForm.controls['hasItem1']" 
                             [value]="_slotsForm.controls['hasItem1'].value" 
                            >
  </app-reactive-radio-select>
  <app-reactive-radio-select [name]="'group' + index" 
                             [value]="!_slotsForm.controls['hasItem2'].value" 
                             [radioItemId]="'hasItem2' + index"
                             [control]="_slotsForm.controls['hasItem2']"
                             >
  </app-reactive-radio-select>
  <app-reactive-radio-select [name]="'group' + index" 
                             [value]="!_slotsForm.controls['hasItem3'].value" 
                             [radioItemId]="'hasItem3' + index"
                             [control]="_slotsForm.controls['hasItem3']"
                            >
  </app-reactive-radio-select>
</div>

Despite setting value as either true or false, both radio buttons appear checked on load.
How can I ensure that only the correct radio button is checked based on the form control's boolean value?
I've verified that the value properties of the form controls are set to either true or false.
Tried initializing the form controls with different boolean values directly in the form group.

It would be helpful if you could provide a minimal reproducible example that shows the problem or error you're encountering, ideally in an online code editor like Stackblitz.

a radio button is to choose between two or more selections (can be two selection true/false) and is a "radio". A checkbox is to select true or false and is a "check". In an input type="radio" you use "value" to give value to the controls when is selected (and all the radio -options- have the same name), in an input type="checkbox" you NOT indicate value.

I understand that using a radio group wrapper would be beneficial for the mentioned case.
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option">
  <mat-radio-button value="1">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>

See doc Angular material 17v radio-button implementation.
